# How can I detect stdout/stderr messages that are written by an unmanaged (P/Invoke) C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a Windows Service, which hosts a WCF Service that invokes some unmanaged C++ DLLs.  Unfortunately, these unmanaged DLLs have some errors/warning that get logged to stderr.  These errors, when logged, signify a failure, and my C# code needs to know about/handle those failures.

How can I redirect/read (from C#) the stdout/stderr messages that the C++ DLLs are generating?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hmm, send it back, you don't want it.

Comment: I don't think GetLastError() is what I'm looking for...

Comment: SetStdHandle. But surely the error reporting is not done via stderr. That does not sound right.

Comment: I haven't looked too deeply at the library that is actually throwing the warning (libpango), as it is a dependency for the code that my interop class invokes.  As far as the actual P/Invoke calls that I'm making, I have proper error handling in place, and no problems are detected when this Pango "warning" is logged to the console.  However, as far as my application is concerned, this "warning" most certainly signifies an error/failure, so I have to detect and handle it.

Comment: So detect it the way I said.